# convert date variable into particular format in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have this yest_date variable in javascript

```
var yest_date = "Mon Dec 12 2016 15:33:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
```

I want this variable 'yest_date' to be in this format and the value is.

```
 20161212
```

Can someone let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: You have a string, just reformat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply convert your string into an actual Date, then use the Date getter methods to extract the values you want into a formatted string:

```js
let yest_date = "Mon Dec 12 2016 15:33:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)"
let date = new Date(yest_date);
console.log(`${date.getFullYear()}${date.getMonth() + 1}${date.getDate()}`)
```

Comment: Hamms- wat is the code inside console.log ? its cryptic. can you please explain the $ sign in there

Comment: It's simply a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: i am getting invalid character when i use as it is whatever values are present inside console.log

Comment: Are you running the code in a browser or with node on the server side?

Comment: running the code in a browser. using tfs of visual studio to write the js code

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use moment.js. It is a very good library to handle any date time related problem http://momentjs.com/

```
var yest_date = moment("Mon Dec 12 2016 15:33:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)")
console.log(yest_date.format("YYYYMMDD"))
```

If you don't want to add an extra library then you can use the classic string concat

```
let yest_date = new Date("Mon Dec 12 2016 15:33:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)")
console.log(`${yest_date.getFullYear()}${yest_date.getMonth() + 1}${yest_date.getDate()}`)
```

Comment: i am getting error when i use this ---> `${yest_date.getFullYear()}${yest_date.getMonth() + 1}${yest_date.getDate()}`

Comment: What is the version and type is your browser? Can you provide the code and the full error log? It works on chrome for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```js
const date = new Date('Mon Dec 12 2016 15:33:41 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)')

const day = date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
const year = date.getFullYear();

const formattedDate = `${year}${month}${day}`;

console.log(formattedDate);
```